# Using jsonpickle in python to parse multiple child attributes

Tags: python, json, parsing

I'm parsing JSON that looks like this:

```
{
    "attr1": true,
    "attr2": "foo",
    "attr3": 7,
    "attr4": [
        {
        "someattr1": "foo",
        "someattr2": "bar"
        },
        {
        "someattr1": "foo",
        "someattr2": "bar"
        },
        ],
    "attr6": false
}
```

How would I go about getting the 2nd attr4's someattr1 using jsonpickle?  Kinda got me lost.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How would I go about getting the 2nd attr4's someattr1 using jsonpickle?

Please note that your json object has an extra comma before the closing square bracket that will make the parser fail. Once removed that, you can:

```
import jsonpickle as jp

json = '''
{
    "attr1": true,
    "attr2": "fooA",
    "attr3": 7,
    "attr4": [
        {
        "someattr1": "fooB",
        "someattr2": "barC"
        },
        {
        "someattr1": "fooD",
        "someattr2": "barE"
        }
        ],
    "attr6": false
} '''

print jp.decode(json)['attr4'][1]['someattr1']  #index == 1 → 2nd in the series!!
```

HTH!

Comment: You mean after the second-to-last curly bracket :)

Comment: @ulvund - aren't we saying the same? :-/

Comment: Good then he can choose any of the ways to look at it and still be right.

Comment: That was obviously made up JSON which I didn't validate, but thanks!